# Is header() in PHP "forgotten" after an internal API request, before responding to the client?

Tags: php, http-headers

Maybe a stupid question, but I've no idea how PHP works in that sense.

Let's say you fire an HTTP Request from a JavaScript client to your PHP Backend. On the server-side in PHP, you then do sth like:

```
// validate input
// process input
header(...);
// execute internal API request, from this server in PHP, using guzzle, 
// curl or whatever, to an external API, and wait for the response
...
echo $response;
```

In other words, when calling `header()` before executing an internal API request, are the HTTP headers sent to the external API, and lost / not forwarded to the JavaScript client in the final response?

Comment: Typically the request/response pair to an internal API would be completely separate to the request/response pair from the incoming request to/from PHP.  How is your internal API being called?

Comment: `header()` sets the headers that are sent from PHP to the client. It has nothing to do with the request sent to the API.

Comment: If your client isn't getting the header, it's a different problem. Check your PHP error log for "Headers already sent" warnings, and fix that problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Wait... are you expecting `header()` to set a _request_ header in your "guzzle, curl or whatever" request? Because it absolutely won't. It will only set a header in the _response_ to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how PHP and your web server are configured, specifically with regard to output/response buffering.

Strictly with regard to PHP:

- If `output_buffering` is enabled then the entire request must complete before *any* response is returned to the client, including HTTP headers.
- If `output_buffering` is not enabled, then the HTTP headers are issued as soon as non-header output is generated. After which trying to set another header results in the classic ["headers already sent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) error.

and of course there's the caveat that buffering can be enabled/disabled/flushed/cleared with [userland code](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), further confusing the issue.

After that it's up to your HTTP server to decide what to do, but generally the default is to forward the headers immediately and buffer the output to some extent so as not to send many small packets where few larger packets will suffice.